# Promise.all() works well in debug mode, but not working in release mode of react native project

Tags: javascript, react-native, request-promise

I am developing a react native project for mobile applications.
The app works fine in debug mode but doesn't work properly after I release the app with CLI.
I think the API request part in `Promise.all()` inside the code below has an issue in release mode.
If anyone has faced similar problems before, then please let me know a suitable solution.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfo('sdf').then(d => {
      const userId = 'sdf';
      Promise.all([
        fetchPortfolio(userId, 'coin'),
        fetchPortfolio(userId, 'idea'),
        getCryptoNews('stocks'),
      ])
        .then(values => {
          dispatch(setCryptoPortfolio(values[0].items ? values[0].items : []));
          dispatch(setIdeaPortfolio(values[1].items ? values[1].items : []));
          setNewsList(values[2].slice(0, 3));
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    });
}, []);
```

It executes the code inside `.catch()` block of the code in release mode.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: The app crashes immediately. I think it doesn't get the response via API, it goes directly to catch() block of exception handling.

Comment: `Promise.all()` rejects as soon as any of the promises passed to it rejects. I assume that one of your network requests fails. As you are probably using different urls for the requests in debug and in release mode, I'd recommend you to check the release urls.

Comment: If you have a try/catch block, then how does your application crash? Also, you are printing a log there...

Comment: The first two requests are sent to fetch the data from firestore, and the third one is from third API. They use the same urls with ones in debug mode.

Comment: In the debug mode, it works well

Comment: You need to look at what the `err` it is catching. One possible failure is that `values[2]` is not an array, but this is just a speculation.

Comment: The third request returns [] when axios request fails.

Comment: The third request fetches data from `http://123.123.123.123: 80/index.php?q=Tesla` with axios. Is that a cause of reject?

Comment: Nothing in the code shown appears to be sensitive to debug vs. release mode. Why are you ignoring the requests to include the actual error message in your post?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in my react native project, where a number of requests were being triggered in Promise.all() and it wasn't catching any error instead it just getting crashed

After hours what i found is, there were api requests having https and http, http requests were working fine in debug mode but not in release mode

Then i simply allowed http requests using this solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24408#issuecomment-490368508

After applying this, every thing got fine